# Filter the mail generated from the Log4j

Tags: grails, log4j, smtpappender

I would like to set the filter in log4j properties in a such way that log4j can only generate the MYSQL related mail. Now i am getting all type of mails from it. I have tried by adding following codes but it has stopped generating the mysql related mail.
So, can you guys help me out on this?

```
        def expFilter = new org.apache.log4j.filter.ExpressionFilter()
        expFilter.setExpression('EXCEPTION ~= com.mysql.jdbc')
        expFilter.setAcceptOnMatch(false)
        expFilter.activateOptions()
        mailAppender.headFilter = expFilter
```

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe you want `setAcceptOnMatch(true)`?

Comment: No, i have tried to test by setting both true and false, but i wont get desire results